Derivative of incomplete gamma function w.r.t. the first argument
Wolfram Research provides the following formulas for the derivative of the incomplete gamma function:
https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/20/01/01/0002/
https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma3/20/01/01/0001/
How can one find an academic reference for these? I have searched extensively through various books but couldn't find anything.
